# Show Time as highest score when game over Unity script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I need help with my script. I really can't understand how to make it. I have a script that counts time but I don't know how to make it so that when the game is over the time appears in my Game Over scene as the highest score. I only need to save this high score for one time. After the game is closed the score can be removed. In the game, I have a countdown timer, when it reaches 0 the game is over.

**This is my TimeCounter script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimeCounter: MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text timerText;
    private float startTime;

    bool finishCountTime = false;

    public string minutes, seconds;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {


    }

    public void startTheTimer()
    {
        Invoke("startTime", 10);
        startTime = Time.time;

    }

    public void stopTheTimer()
    {

        finishCountTime = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {


        float t = Time.time - startTime;
        minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
        seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");
        timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;


    }
}
```

**and this is GameManager script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Threading;

public class GameManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    
    [SerializeField] private float timer = 30;

    private void Awake()
    {
        pop.onClicked += PopClicked;
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        pop.onClicked -= PopClicked;
    }

    private void PopClicked()
    {
        if (pop.Unclicked.Count == 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("GameOver");      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the object that stores the time `DontDestroyOnLoad`. Then add the callback listeners of the scene loading to determine which scene loaded, either your gameover or the game and display/reset the time respectively. If you are unsure of what I mean, I can add a small example. It should also be possible to store the time in a scriptable object. I'm fairly certain that the data is persistent between active sessions but not hard restarts.

Comment: Yes, please add a example it's hard to understand for me. I need to see how it looks. :)

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example snippet of how to use `DontDestroyOnLoad` along with the `SceneLoaded` delegates.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float score;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        var objs = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(ExampleScript));
        
        if (objs.Length > 1)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);   
    }
    
    private void OnEnable()
    {
         SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }
    
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }
    
    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
       if(scene.name == "gameOver")
       {
            // display the time here as we are showing the score   
            Debug.Log(score);
       }
       else
       {
            // we loaded into another scene - presumably your game scene, so reset the score
            score = 0;
       }   
    }
}
```

As it is `DontDestroyOnLoad`, you will need to check if the current scene contains the object already and destroy it. As you have two scripts running your logic, you might need to slightly tweak it so that one of the managers is able to communicate to one another to pull your score or move it to the same script. I have greatly over-generalized your issue as I was not sure which part you did not understand.

Edit: Here is the more in-depth answer on how to achieve what you would like to do.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float score;                // our current score
    private bool updateScore = false;   // whether or not we should update our score UI every frame
    private Text ScoreText = null;      // our text object that updates our score

    private void Awake()
    {
        // as the object is DontDestroyOnLoad, we need to check if another instance exists
        // if one does, we need to delete it as if multiple exist in one scene, there could be issues

        // if a player continually replays your scene where this object starts, then multiple will exist
        var objs = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(TestScript));

        if (objs.Length > 1)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // add the callback for when a scene is loaded
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // remove the callback from when a scene is loaded
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        // grab the new reference to out score UI
        ScoreText = GameObject.Find("Score").GetComponent<Text>();

        // when we have the gameover scene, display our final score
        if (scene.name == "gameover")
        {
            // display the time here as we are showing the score   
            ScoreText.text = "Final Score: " + score.ToString("#");
            updateScore = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // we loaded into another scene - presumably your game scene, so reset the score
            score = 0;
            updateScore = true;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // if we are in the game scene and we should update score, update the score however you like
        if(updateScore)
        {
            score += Time.deltaTime;
            ScoreText.text = "Current Score: " + score.ToString("#");
        }

        // this is here solely for testing - instead of a real game just hit space to end the game and restart it
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "gameover")
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            }
            else
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("gameover");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the script working as well as the two scene hierarchies. For this to work exactly as I have it, you  will need two scenes. In your build settings, the first scene will be your game scene, and then there needs to be some other scene in the build settings with the name `gameover`. As well, you will need to have some sort of `UnityEngine.UI.Text` component that is called `Score` in both scenes.

All of this can be changed, but this is what you need to do to get it to work as I have it set up.
[image: Example]

Comment: Ok, but where I need to put this DontDestroyOnLoad script? Just create an empty game object or how? Maybe we can contact somehow else? I will try to send a print screen and show you what I want to create.

Comment: @EdwardChester It's an example. From the two scripts you posted I would make it your TimeCounter. You would just need to tweak your calls slightly to fit which scene is loaded. In the if else statement I have, place either to start the timer or show the score depending on the scene loaded.

Comment: I really don't know how to do that. I understand what I need and approximately how to need to look like but I can not get it to work.

Comment: @EdwardChester Can you post an update on your answer to what you have now and what is not working?

Comment: Ok. So I have a game that when first scene is open there are pop-it that need to click, when all pop-its are clicked scene changed. In all scenes I want to be on top right side a timer who check how fast I completed scene and when all scene levels are completed or when in scene time countdown 30 sec are ended, automatically opens GameOver scene where you can see your best score (this is time) how fast you are completed all levels and thats it.

Comment: I'm a little confused how you'd want this to work then. If a highscore is your lowest time then completing only one level would give you the best possible score. You never mentioned multiple levels in your original question. Does it show each level we as an individual score?

Comment: No, I mean I just need to create the best time to show up in the GameOver scene/panel. Maybe with GameOvelPanel will be the easiest way how to do that? I have a code but it doesn't show in GameOvelPanel the best time. :(  [This is my code](https://codeshare.io/8pJrWv)

Comment: @EdwardChester Sorry been busy with work. I can make an example that uses multiple scenes that keeps a timer persistent between the two scenes and only increments it in one. Would you like me to add that?

Comment: Yes, it will be great. Thanks! :)

Comment: @EdwardChester Alright posted an updated code snippet with a gif.